# keep getting a parse error on input "::" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
type Mass = Float
type Height = Float
type BMI = Float

  bmi :: Height -> Mass -> BMI
  bmi :: Height-> Mass -> BMI


  bmi heightM weightKg = weightKg/(heightM/100)^2
```

this is my code when running it I keep getting a parse error on :: why is this how can I fix this

Comment: I see two problems here. One is that you've declared the type signature for `bmi` twice. The other is that you have indented blocks which shouldn't be indented.

Comment: you *can* use indentation, but it must be the same indentation.

Answer (score 6):

The structure of Haskell code is determined by its formatting and indentation.

In particular:

```
type BMI = Float

  bmi :: Height -> Mass -> BMI
```

Because the second line is indented more than the first, Haskell assumes it is a continuation of that type declaration. It is parsed as:

```
type BMI = Float bmi :: Height -> Mass -> BMI
```

This is a syntax error because you can't just have a `::` in the middle of a `type` declaration.

Fix: Make sure all your lines are indented the same. In this example you probably don't want any indentation at all:

```
type BMI = Float

bmi :: Height -> Mass -> BMI

^ -- 'type' and 'bmi' start in the same column
```